# Ошибка при вызове метода createFixture в Box2D

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Решил изучить физический движок Box2D в LibGDX. Большинство методов в нем - нативные, и отследить, в чем ошибка, очень трудно. Я создаю физическое тело, и прикрепляю к нему Fixture в конструкторе QuantumCollider без параметров:

```
World world;
BodyDef commonBodyDef;
FixtureDef commonBodyFix;
WorldShell shell;
Box2DDebugRenderer r;
Array<Body> bodies;

public QuantumCollider(String map) throws FileNotFoundException {
    bodies = new Array<Body>();
    r = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    world = new World(new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f), true);
    FileHandle mapFile = Gdx.files.internal("maps/" + map + ".qmap");
    if(!mapFile.exists())
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Can't find a map: " + map);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(mapFile.read());
    Body newWall;
    BodyDef newWallDef = new BodyDef();
    newWallDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
    FixtureDef newWallFix = new FixtureDef();
    PolygonShape newWallShape = new PolygonShape();
    newWallFix.shape = newWallShape;
    String newWallInfo;
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        newWallInfo = scanner.nextLine();
        newWallDef.position.set(Float.parseFloat(newWallInfo.split(" ")[0]), Float.parseFloat(newWallInfo.split(" ")[1]));
        newWallShape.setAsBox(Float.parseFloat(newWallInfo.split(" ")[2]) - newWallDef.position.x + 1, Float.parseFloat(newWallInfo.split(" ")[3]) - newWallDef.position.y + 1);
        newWall = world.createBody(newWallDef);
        newWall.createFixture(newWallFix);
    }
    scanner.close();
    newWallShape.dispose();
    commonBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    commonBodyFix = new FixtureDef();
    commonBodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    commonBodyDef.position.set(random(1000), random(1000));
    commonBodyFix.restitution = 1.2f;
    commonBodyFix.density = 0.01f;
    commonBodyFix.friction = 0.5f;
    CircleShape commonBodyShape = new CircleShape();
    commonBodyShape.setRadius(10.0f);
    commonBodyFix.shape = commonBodyShape;
    commonBodyShape.dispose();
}

public QuantumCollider() throws FileNotFoundException {
    this("ps_explosion");
    Body nobody;
    nobody = world.createBody(commonBodyDef);
    nobody.createFixture(commonBodyFix);
    nobody.applyForceToCenter(71, 71, true);
}
```

И если само тело создается нормально, то при вызове метода nobody.createFixture() вылетает вот такая ошибка:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже читал про то, что нельзя изменять мир/тела во время вызова функции World.step(), однако это тело создается до вызова каких бы то ни было функций вроде render() или step(). В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: проблема в том, что в нативном модуле вылетело исключение, и нужно отлаживать его, чтобы узнать что произошло. в тексте ошибки ниже есть stacktrace до места, где произошла ошибка

Answer (score 3):

Вопрос был задан давно но все равно отвечу. Вызов

```
nobody.createFixture(commonBodyFix);
```

Должен быть до `commonBodyShape.dispose();` а у Вас после.